# ROR: Check object inclusion in polymorphic association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm looking for a way to check if certain object is included in polymorphic association.

My example is

**language.rb (this is essentially a list of available languages)**

```
has_many :user_languages
```

**user_language.rb**

```
belongs_to :language
belongs_to :speakable, :polymorphic => true
```

**user.rb**

```
has_many :languages, :class_name => 'UserLanguage', :as => :speakable
```

Now i want to check is user has certain language. The idea I had is to use `include?` method in a form of

```
u = User.find(1)
l = Language.find(1)
u.languages.include?(l)
```

but it always returns `false` although `u.languages` gives

`#<UserLanguage id: 1, language_id: 1, speakable_id: 1, speakable_type: "User">`

What would be the proper way to arrange this check?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your problems lies right here

```
has_many :languages, :class_name => 'UserLanguage', :as => :speakable
```

Because you set `class_name` to `UserLanguage`, `u.languages` is giving you a set of `UserLanguage` objects not `Language` objects.

If you change your `user.rb` associations, as below, `u.languages` should give you what you're looking for.

```
has_many :user_languages, :as => :speakable
has_many :languages, :through => :user_languages
```